# web.config error is displayed in german, how do i change this to english

Tags: .net, iis, web-config

I purposely broke the web.config in order to recreate this problem so the error is not the problem, it is the language it is displayed in that is the problem. How do I change this to english.

I have removed German language from both "Region & Language" and the "Language" in the Control panel. See images below.

[image: Web.config IIS error]

below shows that I do not have Germin language on my machine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Go to Programs to see if you have a language pack installed for .NET Framework.

Comment: @LexLi do you mean Program and Features

Comment: @LexLi if that is what you mean, no it is not on the list